# Why does dynamically applied memory region initialization affect the contents of other regions of memory?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "dpi_lyric.h"

int main(){
  char *lyric_row[100] = {NULL};
  char *filepath = "./lrc/简单爱.lrc";
  char *lyric_str = NULL;
  int file_line_num = 0;
  LRC *head = NULL;

  lyric_str=ReadLyricFile(filepath);
  LyricFileSplit(lyric_str,&file_line_num,lyric_row);
  DpiLyricHead(lyric_row);
  DpiLyricSub(lyric_row,file_line_num,&head);
  TraverLyricLink(head);

  return 0;
}
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "dpi_lyric.h"


char *ReadLyricFile(char *filepath){
  int file_size = 0,status;
  char *lyric_str = NULL;
  FILE *fp = fopen(filepath,"rb");//读取文件
  if(fp == NULL){//文件打开错误
    printf("Lyric File Open Error!\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
  file_size = ftell(fp);
  rewind(fp);

  lyric_str = (char*)malloc(file_size);
  if(lyric_str == NULL){//内存分配失败
    printf("Memory Alloc Failed!\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  status = fread(lyric_str,file_size,1,fp);
  if(status != 1){//歌词文件读取失败
    printf("Lyric File Read Failed!\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  fclose(fp);

  return lyric_str;

}


void LyricFileSplit(char *lyric_str,int *file_line_num,char *lyric_row[]){
  char *split_str = "\r\n";
  int i = 0;
  lyric_row[(*file_line_num)] = strtok(lyric_str,split_str);
  while(lyric_row[(*file_line_num)] != NULL){
    ++(*file_line_num);
    lyric_row[(*file_line_num)] = strtok(NULL,split_str);
  }

  for(;i < *file_line_num;i++){
    printf("%d %s\n",strlen(lyric_row[i]),lyric_row[i]);
  }

  free(lyric_str);
}

/**
 * @description: 
 * @param {char} *lyric_row =
 * @return {*} 
 */
void DpiLyricHead(char *lyric_row[]){
  int i = 0;
  char *mid_str = NULL;
  char *head_name[4] = {"歌曲名:","歌手:","专辑:","LRC文件创建者:"};
  char *head[4] = {NULL};
  char *format[4] = {"[ti:","[ar:","[al:","[by:"};
  for(;i < 4;i++){
    mid_str = lyric_row[i];
    if(strstr(mid_str,format[i]) != NULL){
      head[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
      sscanf(mid_str,"%*[^:]:%[^]]",head[i]);
    }

    printf("%s %s\n",head_name[i],head[i]);
    free(head[i]);
  }
}


void DpiLyricSub(char *lyric_row[],int file_line_num,LRC **head){
  int i,j,time_num,time[6];
  char *mid_str = NULL;
  char minute[3],second[6];

  for(i = 4;i < file_line_num;i++){
    time_num = 0;
    time[6] = 0;
    //printf("判断：%s\n",lyric_row[i]);
    mid_str = lyric_row[i];
    while(*mid_str == '['){
      strncpy(minute,mid_str+1,2);
      minute[2] = '\0';
      strncpy(second,mid_str+4,5);
      second[5] = '\0';
      time[time_num] = atoi(minute)*60 + atoi(second);
      time_num++;
      mid_str = mid_str+10;
    }

    for(j = 0;j < time_num;j++){
      if(InsertNodeSort(head,time,mid_str,j) != 0){
        printf("Insert Node Failed!\n");
        return ;
      }
    }
  }
}




int InsertNodeSort(LRC **head,int time[],char *mid_str,int j){
  LRC *lrc = (LRC*)malloc(sizeof(LRC));
  if(lrc == NULL){
    printf("Lrc Node Malloc Failed!\n");
    return -1;
  }else{
    strcpy(lrc->lrc_buf,"\0");
    lrc->lrc_cur_num = 0;
    lrc->next = NULL;
    lrc->time = 0;
  }

  lrc->time = time[j];
  strcpy(lrc->lrc_buf,mid_str);
  
  LRC *pos = NULL;
  LRC *pos_next = NULL;
  if(*head == NULL){
    *head = lrc;
    lrc->next = NULL;
    return 0;
  }

  if((*head)->time > lrc->time){
    lrc->next = *head;
    *head = lrc;
    return 0;
  }

  pos = *head;
  pos_next = pos->next;
  
  while(pos_next != NULL){
    if(pos->time < lrc->time && 
      lrc->time < pos_next->time){
        lrc->next = pos_next;
        pos->next = lrc;
        return 0;
      }

      pos = pos_next;
      pos_next = pos_next->next;
  }

  pos->next = lrc;
  lrc->next = NULL;
  return 0;

}

void TraverLyricLink(LRC *head){
  LRC *mov = head;
  if(head == NULL){
    printf("Link Empty!\n");
    return ;
  }
  while(mov != NULL){
    printf("%s %d\n",mov->lrc_buf,mov->time);
    mov = mov->next;
  }
}
```

```
#ifndef _DPI_LYRIC_H_
#define _DPI_LYRIC_H_

typedef struct lrc
{
  int time;
  char lrc_buf[200];
  int lrc_cur_num;
  struct lrc *next;
}LRC;


extern char *ReadLyricFile(char *filepath);


extern void LyricFileSplit(char *lyric_str,int *file_line_num,char *lyric_row[]);


extern void DpiLyricHead(char *lyric_row[]);


extern void DpiLyricSub(char *lyric_row[],int file_line_num,LRC **head);


extern int InsertNodeSort(LRC **head,int time[],char *mid_str,int j);

extern void TraverLyricLink(LRC *head);

#endif
```

```
[ti:简单爱]
[ar:周杰伦]
[al:范特西]
[by:大脸猫]
[00:04.41]周杰伦 Chow, Jay Jou
[00:07.41]aaaaaaaaaaa
[00:10.56]简单爱(台视Star blue蓝星主题曲)
[00:15.56]bbbbbbbbb
[00:18.48]词：徐若瑄 曲：周杰伦
[00:24.51]cccccccccccc
[00:26.44]说不上为什么 我变得很主动
[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做
[02:04.94][00:36.09]我想大声宣布 对你依依不舍
[02:09.97][00:41.26]连隔壁邻居都猜到我现在的感受
[02:14.94][00:46.17]河边的风 在吹着头发 飘动
[02:19.80][00:51.25]牵着你的手 一阵莫名感动
[02:24.61][00:55.86]我想带你 回我的外婆家
[02:28.32][00:59.79]一起看着日落 一直到我们都睡着
[03:34.64][02:34.71][01:05.83]我想就这样牵着你的手不放开
[03:39.68][02:39.34][01:10.71]爱能不能够永远单纯没有悲哀
[03:44.27][02:43.90][01:15.44]我想 带你骑单车
[03:46.74][02:46.60][01:18.05]我想 和你看棒球
[03:49.77][02:49.58][01:20.71]想这样没担忧
[03:51.61][02:51.59][01:22.69]唱着歌 一直走☆
[03:54.38][02:54.35][01:25.57]我想就这样牵着你的手不放开
[03:59.19][02:59.01][01:30.41]爱可不可以简简单单没有伤害
[04:03.77][03:03.73][01:35.04]你 靠着我的肩膀
[04:06.33][03:06.26][01:37.49]你 在我胸口睡着
[04:09.13][03:09.34][01:40.57]像这样的生活
[04:11.36][03:11.26][01:42.66]我爱你 你爱我★
[03:13.76][01:44.97]想～～～ 简！简！单！单！ 爱～～～
[03:23.61][01:54.30]想～～～ 简！简！单！单！ 爱～～～
```

```
DpiLyricSub (lyric_row=0x7fffffffdff0, file_line_num=32, head=0x7fffffffdfe0) at dpi_lyric.c:127
127         for(j = 0;j < time_num;j++){
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
112       for(i = 4;i < file_line_num;i++){
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) p i
$6 = 11
(gdb) s
113         time_num = 0;
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
114         time[6] = 0;
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
116         mid_str = lyric_row[i];
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
117         while(*mid_str == '['){
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
118           strncpy(minute,mid_str+1,2);
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
119           minute[2] = '\0';
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
120           strncpy(second,mid_str+4,5);
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
121           second[5] = '\0';
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
122           time[time_num] = atoi(minute)*60 + atoi(second);
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
123           time_num++;
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
124           mid_str = mid_str+10;
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
117         while(*mid_str == '['){
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
118           strncpy(minute,mid_str+1,2);
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
119           minute[2] = '\0';
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
120           strncpy(second,mid_str+4,5);
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
121           second[5] = '\0';
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
122           time[time_num] = atoi(minute)*60 + atoi(second);
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
123           time_num++;
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
124           mid_str = mid_str+10;
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
117         while(*mid_str == '['){
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
127         for(j = 0;j < time_num;j++){
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
128           if(InsertNodeSort(head,time,mid_str,j) != 0){
3: lyric_row[11] = 0x603388 "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) 
InsertNodeSort (head=0x7fffffffdfe0, time=0x7fffffffdf90, mid_str=0x6033d3 "我想大声宣布 对你依依不舍", j=0)
    at dpi_lyric.c:147
147       LRC *lrc = (LRC*)malloc(sizeof(LRC));
(gdb) x/s 0x603388
0x603388:       "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什么都会值得去做"
(gdb) s
148       if(lrc == NULL){
(gdb) x/s 0x603388
0x603388:       "[00:31.37]若爱上一个人 什a\f\002"
(gdb)
```

The environment is centos7.This is a lyric parsing small program, the main process is to read the lrc lyric file, split the file by line, and then insert the lyric content into the linked list according to the time label.

The above is all my code, and the problem I am facing now is that Chinese garbled characters will appear when I traverse the node at the last time. After gdb investigation, it is found that the content of the string in lyric_row[] was changed when applying for the node and initializing it. I am very confused about why these two different memory regions conflict, but what is even more incredible is that, When I changed the size of lrc_buf[200] in the struct to lrc_buf[2000], this situation disappeared again, but I looked at the size of the string in lyric_row[], it is impossible to need so much memory, I wonder why this is happening?

I would like to know why this happened, is there any error in my code that I have not found or other circumstances, please answer, thank you very much.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a very important thing about strings: That they're really called ***null-terminated** strings*. A string of `file_size` characters needs `file_size + 1` characters of storage to also contain the null-terminator. Also, `fread` will *not* add the terminator, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: And a general tip for avoiding and solving problems early: Don't write everything at once. Instead start with an empty `main` function. Build with extra warnings enabled, treated as errors. When it builds cleanly test everything. When it passes the tests, add only a couple of lines. Build and test as before. When you get a problem, it will be much easier to locate when and where it happens, and to debug it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reminding. I will correct my programming habits. I will try the method you mentioned after dinner

Comment: I tried your method of adding '\0' to the end of the lyric_str, but the situation did not improve, and it still happened that the content of the string in lyric_row[] was changed when the node memory was requested

Comment: Take a few steps back, make sure that you read the file okay, and that you allocate enough memory for the null-terminator. Once that's done, call the function to split the input, but instead of saving the lines in an array, just print them, to make sure that all lines are split correctly. And make sure that you don't have too many lines for your array. Then save it in your array, and make sure you have a correct counter for the number of lines. Then add to the lists, making sure that you don't go out of bounds of the array `lrc_buf`. I.e. that the strings will be less than 200 characters.

Comment: Make sure that the `lrc_buf` arrays are also properly null-terminated. In short: Do one small and simple bit at a time, with testing in between.

Comment: I also suggest that you take this as the perfect opportunity to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the program line by line while monitoring variables and their values. When you go out of bounds of any of your arrays or strings (which I guess is the problem) that should be easy to see then.

Comment: And depending on the compiler you use, you could use its built-in *sanitizer* to help you find problems like this. For example, if you use GCC then add `-g -fsanitize=address` to get a detailed report when you do something wrong in the code. And as mentioned, [build with extra warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/nWP48TfP7). Clang reports one warning that is *very* important and relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried it step by step according to your method, but there is still no change, and I have not found the problem so far. I attached the gdb debugging process to the back of the problem, and you can see that when malloc created a new node, the original memory area of lyric_row[11] changed, and the original thing disappeared

Comment: Also note that `strtok(lyric_str,split_str)` will *not* "tokenize" the string on the full `split_str`. It will split the string on *either* `'\r'` *or* `'\n'`. Lucky for you, the `strtok` will skip consecutive separator characters. Also note that `strtok` *modifies* the source string, by replacing the found separator characters with the string terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `LyricFileSplit` function:

```
void LyricFileSplit(char *lyric_str,int *file_line_num,char *lyric_row[]){
  char *split_str = "\r\n";
  int i = 0;
  lyric_row[(*file_line_num)] = strtok(lyric_str,split_str);
  // ...
  free(lyric_str);
}
```

The problem here is that `strtok` doesn't create new strings. It return pointers to the elements of the source string `lyrics_str`.

When you `free` that string, all the pointers in `lyric_row` becomes invalid.

You should keep the `lyrics_str` pointer valid until the end of the program.

This behavior of [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) is well documented.

Comment: My God, you have solved the problem that has been bothering me all day so quickly. Thank you very much. I am worried to death about this problem

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope I can be as good as you one day